# dynamically change document title and back

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying dynamically change the document title in my app. It's a simple timer app with countdown, so the idea is during countdown duplicate countdown in a document title (it is working), but I want when countdown is done show back app title in a document title. Now it is showing next timer session (and its ok, I wrote this logic for the timer). But for the title I want after timer is done reset title to the default (appTitle). How I can do it?

```
title = 'appTitle';

ngOnInit() {
this.timerService.time$.subscribe((time) => {
  this.titleTimer.setTitle(this.datePipe.transform(time, 'mm:ss'));
});
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the time is equal to the `BREAKING_TIME`, and set the original title:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.timerService.time$.subscribe((time) => {
        if (time == BREAKING_TIME)
            this.titleTimer.setTitle(this.title);            
        else
            this.titleTimer.setTitle(this.datePipe.transform(time, 'mm:ss'));
    });
}
```